# problems with css and background image

Tags: html, css

I have a container with a height of 100% so the height will be dynamically changed to text inside the container.

anyway, the container have a background with a custom image (using background-image).

now, when I create a < div id=blabla" > with { float:left; width: 100px; height:100%; }, the background which defined in my container doesnt show on the div.

but if I remove the float:left, the background does shows up

any ideas what the problem could be ?

Comment: Can you post some code? Also, what browser are you using? I cannot reproduce this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, add the following as you mention to the container element.

```
overflow: hidden;
```

If you are still seeing this issue in IE6/7, you will need to enforce hasLayout, this is done by adding this to the container element.

```
zoom: 1;
```

Hope the IE6/7 addition helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear from  your question but I'm assuming the floated div is a separate div inside of the container div?  By default a floated item is not "contained" by the container.  This is just the way floats are supposed to behave.  If you put "overflow:auto;" on the container div then you will generally get the behavior you desire, but read a more thorough discussion of the topic here: http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/59

Answer (score 0):

I made it.

The solution was to add

```
overflow:hidden;
```

to the container div.